# Operator ?? null coalescing in XNA 4 inside if statement

Tags: xna, operators, null-coalescing-operator

How can I fix my code under this text?

```
//puncts = puncts ?? new List<Vector2>() { new Vector2(position.X, position.Y) };

if (Vector2.Distance(position, puncts[indexpunkt] = puncts[indexpunkt]  ??  new Vector2(position.X, position.Y)   ) < 1)
                indexpunkt++;
```

Error:

```
Error   1   Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2' and 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector2'
```

I wish create new puncts if it is null and add first element to its list.
Can I use operator `??` and how can I **use it in** `if` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector2` is a `Struct` and therefore cannot be null, so coalescing operators don't apply.

Comment: so, I cannot do anything in if statement with my vector2?

Comment: you can do lots of things in an if statement with a vector2, you just can't check if it is null. That would be like saying int i; if(i == null){...}

Comment: Actually it would probably be more like saying int i; if(i == "hello") {...}